# View Holders Data messing up while scrolling in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Hi Community,

> I'm developing whats-app like application.In that I am facing a
>   problem in recycle view while scrolling the items.The problem is even
>   specific to audio files itself.These files were playing irrelevant to
>   item data position.Please help me to resolve this issue.

**MyAdapterClass:**

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SwappingHolder holder, int position) {
        MessageDetails messageData = messagesList.get(position);

        if (messageData != null) {
            switch (messageData.getMessageType()) {
                case MessageDetails.MESSAGE_TEXT_TYPE:
                    TextTypeViewHolder textViewHolder = (TextTypeViewHolder) holder;
                    textViewHolder.updateView(messageData);
                    break;
                case MessageDetails.MESSAGE_IMAGE_TYPE:
                    ImageTypeViewHolder imageViewHolder = (ImageTypeViewHolder) holder;
                    imageViewHolder.updateImageFile(messageData);
                    break;
                case MessageDetails.MESSAGE_AUDIO_TYPE:
                    AudioTypeViewHolder audioHolder = (AudioTypeViewHolder) holder;
                    audioHolder.initializeAudioPlayer(messageData);
                    break;
                case MessageDetails.MESSAGE_VIDEO_TYPE:
                    VideoTypeViewHolder videoHolder = (VideoTypeViewHolder) holder;
                    videoHolder.updateVideoMessage(messageData);
                    break;
                case MessageDetails.MESSAGE_LOCATION_TYPE:
                    MapTypeHolder mapHolder = (MapTypeHolder) holder;
                    mapHolder.loadMapThumbView(messageData);
                    break;
                case MessageDetails.MESSAGE_CONTACT_TYPE:
                    ContactsTypeHolder contactsHolder = (ContactsTypeHolder) holder;
                    contactsHolder.setContactData(messageData);
                    break;
                case MessageDetails.MESSAGE_FILE_TYPE:
                     FileTypeHolder fileTypeHolder = (FileTypeHolder)holder;
                     fileTypeHolder.updateFileData(messageData);
            }
        }
    }
```

**MyHolderClass:**

```
 public class AudioTypeViewHolder extends SwappingHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener {
        SeekBar seekBar;
        TextView timer, tv_time;
        ImageView btn_play, iv_smile;
        CardView cardView;
        RelativeLayout parentView;
        CustomizedAudioPlayer player;
        MessageDetails messageDetails;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

        public AudioTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView, multiSelector);
            this.timer = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timer);
            this.seekBar = (SeekBar) itemView.findViewById(R.id.audio_seekBar);
            this.btn_play = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
            this.tv_time = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.timeright);
            this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            this.parentView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.parent_view);
            this.iv_smile  =(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.smile1);
            this.mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

            btn_play.setOnClickListener(this);
            player = new CustomizedAudioPlayer(mediaPlayer, seekBar, btn_play, timer);
            itemView.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            itemView.setLongClickable(true);
            btn_play.setOnLongClickListener(this);
            btn_play.setLongClickable(true);
        }

        void initializeAudioPlayer(MessageDetails messageDetails) {
            int colorId, gravity;
            this.messageDetails = messageDetails;

                if(messageDetails.getAudioPlayer() == null)
                    messageDetails.setAudioPlayer(player);

                if (messageDetails.getSender().equals("to")) {
                    colorId = mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_recevied_item);
                    gravity = Gravity.LEFT;
                    iv_smile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                } else {
                    colorId = mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.color_sent_item);
                    gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                    iv_smile.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    iv_smile.setBackgroundResource(updateMessageStatus(messageDetails.getMstatus()));
                }

                player.initializePlayer(messageDetails.getMessage());
                tv_time.setText(messageDetails.getTime());
                cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(colorId);
                parentView.setGravity(gravity);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int id = view.getId();
            if (id == R.id.btnPlay) {

                if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                    // check my player is playing
                    //if not, stop if any other player is playing
                    for (MessageDetails messageDetails : messagesList) {
                        CustomizedAudioPlayer customPlayer = messageDetails.getAudioPlayer();
                        if(customPlayer != null)
                            customPlayer.stopTheMediaPlay();
                    }

                    //start my player
                    btn_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_pause);
                    player.startThePlayer();
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    btn_play.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_play);
                    player.stopTheMediaPlay();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
            onItemLongPressed(this, messageDetails);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**My Custom Audio Player**

```
public class CustomizedAudioPlayer implements SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener,MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener, MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener {
    private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
    SeekBar seekbar;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean isPaused;
    ImageView playBtn;
    TextView timer;
    StringBuilder mFormatBuilder;
    Formatter mFormatter;
    int totalDuration, currentDuration;
    String path, chatId;

    public  CustomizedAudioPlayer(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, SeekBar seekbar, ImageView view, TextView timer){
        this.seekbar = seekbar;
        this.playBtn = view;
        this.timer = timer;
        this.mediaPlayer = mediaPlayer;

        mFormatBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        mFormatter = new Formatter(mFormatBuilder, Locale.getDefault());

        this.seekbar.setProgress(0);
        this.seekbar.setMax(100);
        this.seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    public void initializePlayer(String filePath){
        try{
            if(path == null){
                this.path = filePath;
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(path);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                timer.setText(stringForTime( mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){

        }
    }

    public void startThePlayer(){
        totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentDuration);
        myHandler.postDelayed(updateProgress,100);
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    public void stopTheMediaPlay(){
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_play);
            currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            timer.setText(stringForTime( mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
            myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateProgress);
            mediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_play);
        seekbar.setProgress(0);
        timer.setText(stringForTime( mediaPlayer.getDuration()));
        myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateProgress);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                myHandler.removeCallbacks(updateProgress);
                playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_play);
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                isPaused = true;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        currentDuration = progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
            if (mediaPlayer != null && mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                if(fromUser){
                    mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentDuration);
                }
            } else if (mediaPlayer == null) {
                seekBar.setProgress(0);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        currentDuration = progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() &&  mediaPlayer != null || (isPaused &&  mediaPlayer != null)) {
                isPaused = false;
                mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentDuration);
                myHandler.postDelayed(updateProgress,100);
                mediaPlayer.start();
                playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_pause);
            }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer, int i, int i1) {
        return false;
    }

    private Runnable updateProgress = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
            currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
            int progress = getProgressPercentage();

            float progressPer = ((float)progress/100);
            float newPosition = (totalDuration) * progressPer;

            seekbar.setProgress(progress);
            timer.setText(stringForTime( (int) newPosition));
            myHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };


    private String stringForTime(int timeMs) {
        int totalSeconds = timeMs / 1000;

        int seconds = totalSeconds % 60;
        int minutes = (totalSeconds / 60) % 60;
        int hours   = totalSeconds / 3600;

        mFormatBuilder.setLength(0);
        if (hours > 0) {
            return mFormatter.format("%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, seconds).toString();
        } else {
            return mFormatter.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds).toString();
        }
    }

    public int getProgressPercentage(){
        long currentSeconds = (currentDuration / 1000);
        long totalSeconds = (totalDuration / 1000);
        Double percentage =(((double)currentSeconds)/totalSeconds)*100;
        return percentage.intValue();
    }

    public int progressToTimer(int progress, int totalDuration) {
        totalDuration = (totalDuration / 1000);
        int currentDuration = (int) ((((double)progress) / 100) * totalDuration);

        // return current duration in milliseconds
        return currentDuration * 1000;
    }
}
```

I even tried by placing

> setIsRecyclable(false);

Using this, the positions of items are stable, but the item not updating while playing audio file(i.e. seekbar, file time not updating)

You can closely find my problem in following screenshot

[image: Before Scrolling] 
[image: After Scrolling]

Comment: Change to `messagesList.get(holder.getAdapterPosition())`

Comment: It didn't solved the issue.

Comment: @Rama did you make it work?